# Set Windows to close application when the lid is being closed

Tags: windows, events, lid, hook

I need to be able to configure Windows 7+ to close all instances of Microsoft Remote Desktop application when the lid of the laptop is being closed. On MacOS I can achieve this via osascript. Could this be done in Windows?